# What is the "Law of Causality"?

Tags: causation, causality

Is there a Law of Causality? Or a principle of Causality?
Someone used that in an argument with me and I couldn't find much information on the subject.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: See [Causal Processes](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/causation-process/) and [The Metaphysics of Causation](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/causation-metaphysics/) and [Laws of Nature](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/laws-of-nature/) with many further links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The** 'Law of Causality' will most certainly be something similar to:

> Every event is an effect of a cause.

Or, even easier:

> Every event has a cause.

One example for a canonical formulation of the Law of Causality (as different from the countless 
*empirical* laws of causality) can be found in Kant's *Critique of Pure Reason*:

> [...] the [...] natural law of causality that **everything contingent must have a cause**, [...] (A605/B633, fn., emphasis mine)

Another proposal and very condensed discussion is formulated by Wittgenstein in his (in-)famous *Tractatus logico-philosophicus*:

> 6.32 **The law of causality is not a law but the form of a law**.
>
> 6.321 ‘Law of causality’—that is a general name. And just as
>   in mechanics, for example, there are ‘minimum-
>   principles’, such as the law of least action, so too in
>   physics there are causal laws, laws of the causal form.
>
> [...]
>
> 6.36 If there were a law of causality, it might be put in the
>   following way: **There are laws of nature**.
>
> 6.361 One might say, using Hertz’s terminology, that only
>   connexions that are subject to law are thinkable.
>
> 6.3611 We cannot compare a process with ‘the passage of
>   time’—there is no such thing—but only with another
>   process (such as the working of a chronometer).
>   Hence we can describe the lapse of time only by relying
>   on some other process.
>   Something exactly analogous applies to space: e.g.
>   when people say that neither of two events (which
>   exclude one another) can occur, because there is nothing
>   to cause the one to occur rather than the other, **it is really a
>   matter of our being unable to describe one of the two
>   events unless there is some sort of asymmetry to be
>   found**. And if such an asymmetry is to be found, we can
>   regard it as the cause of the occurrence of the one and the
>   non-occurrence of the other.
>
> (Translated by D. F. Pears and B. F. McGuinness, Routledge 1974, emphasis mine)

In both cases (Kant as well, but it would take too much place to consider that here) the idea is that in order to *perceive something as a particular object/event at all*, we must have a difference, an assymetry in space-time, the *other*. That is our mode of perception, therefore an underlying, necessary principle of (our!) reality. And as both Kant and Wittgenstein point out here, neither time nor space are absolutely objective, just as this "law" is not.

In this sense, it is a *principle of the human mode of perception and thought*. And therefore very fundamental for each empirical law.

Comment: I think the first enunciation is better formulated than the second. I have 2 follow up questions (I hope it's ok for me to ask here, if not, I'll ask a new question): 1- Is this law independent of empirical facts? For instance if quantum physics disproved empirical causality as a fundamental phenomena, would it still be logically true that every event requires a cause? 2 - is time a prerequisite (as it seems to be in empirical laws)?

Comment: @jony: I hope the edit clarifies these aspects of your question, esp. our inability to disprove something that is the very constituent of our ability to think something *as something particular*.

Comment: @jony : Quantum physics cannot disprove the law of causality, since the law of causality is not an empirical causal law. The law of causality is a metaphysical claim that we need to **presuppose** with a view to looking for empirical laws in nature. What quantum physics can do is try to avoid the presupposition, not refute it.

Comment: @n.r. Of course not without other metaphysical and methodological commitments people normally not care to justify which in the end often end up in the very same thought; bare in mind that what quantum physics describe are not so much particular events or processes, but rather abstract states of systems. The transition to the immediate/concrete/particular is exactly what physics is still working on. In this sense it is a categorically (sic!) different description of the very same (I refuse to talk about "thing" or "object" here, as this entails metaphysical implications).

Comment: is it a definition of "cause"? @PhilipKlöcking

Comment: No, it is not a definition of cause. It presupposes that there are causes, without saying what a cause is, and states that every event has a cause.

Comment: @MATHEMETICIAN: As said, it is the form of any law of causation, whereas causation itself is defined/described in various ways. See [here](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/40359/is-there-any-scientific-documenation-expatiating-upon-the-law-of-cause-and-effec/40360#40360).

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking hmm what do you mean "form" i assume not "definition" of a universal term?

Comment: Form is the logical form. By the way, aren't we running together the Law of Causality (the metaphysical claim that all events have causes) and a thesis about the logical form of all causal statements? Aren't these separate issues? Kant and Wittgenstein don't seem to be talking about the same thing under the "law of causality" heading.